# Retrieving password from Windows Credential Manager using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-prompt, credential-manager

I am trying to add and retrieve credentials from Windows Credential Manager using a command prompt.

To add a new credential, I have the command like below and it works perfectly:

```
cmdkey /add:testTarget /user:testUser /pass:testPassword
```

However, when I try to retrieve the credentials, which I have added earlier (testTraget) using CMD, I am unable to get the password using the command below:

```
cmdkey /list:testTarget
```

The command only returns the Target(testTarget),Type(Domain Password), and the Username(testUser)

How can I retrieve the testUser password?

I know this is possible in Mac OS using Bash and keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"How can I retrieve the testUser password?"**

This is not possible using `cmdkey`.

**Reference** [cmdkey](http://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html):

> Create, list or delete stored user names, passwords or credentials.

...

> **Once stored, passwords are not displayed.**

Comment: Begs the question what are they stored for?

Comment: now we know we can't use cmdkey to do that... something should be able to interact with the store to retrieve the password... what is it?

Comment: @user1885834 _(shrug)_ I've no idea.

Comment: I came here looking for the same answer. Looking for something like `security` command on macOS.

Comment: The credential manager uses Kerberos tickets. You cannot get the password out because it doesn't store the password. The uses of kerberos tickets are many in Windows. By default it's used for RDP connections, and SMB connections. For example: `net use` will automatically pull the credential if you don't specify one.

Comment: @HackSlash not sure what you mean, Credential Manager definitely stores the passwords and the OG `Credman` library allows you to fetch it: https://github.com/sergeypopov13/CredMan

Comment: @OhadSchneider that is for `Generic Credentials` and not `Windows Credentials`. There are many types of credentials you can store in the manager. In the OP question the example given would make a `Windows Credential` which is used for RDP and SMB connections. This is NTLM, which is a hash of the password or a ticket: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/microsoft-ntlm

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to work with passwords from cmdkey's credentialstore using powershell and the `Credman.ps1` library.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde

Add credentials as system user (after a `psexec -s` in administrator's powershell console). Run powershell script as system user as well (ie. in task scheduler tasks) for safe usage.

To learn more about Sysinternal's psExec and cmdkey see this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/1206443/how-to-add-cached-credentials-for-the-windows-system-acount

--

**Adding a password**

```
cmdkey /generic:Foo /user:bar /pass:banana
```

**Retrieving plain-text password with powershell**

```
. "Credman.ps1"

$CredKey = "Foo"

$sourceCredential = Read-Creds $CredKey
$pass = $sourceCredential.CredentialBlob.tostring()
write-host $pass
```

Comment: This is cool but you should note that this only works for generic credentials because `Windows Credentials` don't store the password at all.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is access to a secure vault (and not necessarily the Credential Manager), there is now a **cross-platform** (linux/mac/Windows) solution in PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/secretmanagement/get-started/using-secretstore?view=ps-modules

```bash
# One time
Register-SecretVault -Name SecretStore -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault

Set-Secret -Name "testUser" -Secret "testPassword"
Get-Secret -Name "testUser" -AsPlainText

# Show secret metadata
Get-SecretInfo
```

Comment: This is hilarious because now you need a password to get your other passwords. Where do you store that one? This is great for interactive use but doesn't work for automation as you've just moved the cheese.

Comment: I was also disappointed Credential Manager wasn't used, but there are available Credential Manager based implementations of secure vaults (which you could use in automation if executed under your account): https://github.com/PowerShell/SecretStore/issues/103#issuecomment-1872348318